# Can't get local DB to work with application when on another PC

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, localdb

So I have this application I wrote as a little project for work. It uses a single database table that was set up within Visual Studio along with the application itself. And while it runs perfectly fine on my own laptop, I can't get it to work on another PC.

Having done a bit research I've read about having to install SqlLocalDB.MSI. So I did just do that, but even then I constantly keep getting an error telling me that the database instance cannot be found.

At first I thought it could have something to do with the location of the database file(s), but even after a test where I put those files in the same kind of location as on my laptop (which is the C: drive) it just doesn't work.

I have honestly no idea what I'm doing wrong here. Anyone who might have an idea what I could do to get it to work correctly?

The full error I've received:

> Zie het einde van dit bericht voor meer informatie over het aanroepen 
>   van JIT-foutopsporing (Just In Time) in plaats van dit dialoogvenster.
>
> ************** Tekst van uitzondering ************** System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Er is een netwerkfout
>   of een exemplaarspecifieke fout opgetreden tijdens het maken van
>   verbinding met SQL Server. De server is niet gevonden of is niet
>   toegankelijk. Controleer of de exemplaarnaam correct is en of in de
>   instellingen van SQL Server externe verbindingen zijn toegestaan.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Er is een fout in de
>   Local Database Runtime opgetreden. The specified LocalDB instance does
>   not exist. )    bij
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager
>   sqlAuthProviderManager)    bij
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    bij
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    bij
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection)    bij
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection)    bij
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    bij
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    bij
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)    bij
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    bij
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    bij
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    bij
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    bij System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    bij
>   Aanwezigheidssysteem.Database.LoadEmployees()    bij
>   Aanwezigheidssysteem.Hoofdmenu.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
>   bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    bij
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()    bij
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>   bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()    bij
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    bij
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    bij
>   System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)    bij
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    bij
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)    bij
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    bij System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>   ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 Error
>   Number:-1983577849,State:0,Class:20
>
> ************** Geladen assembly's ************** mscorlib
>       Assembly-versie: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32-versie: 4.7.3110.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- DRPAttendanceSystem
>       Assembly-versie: 1.0.0.0
>       Win32-versie: 1.0.0.0
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/DeBeerSoftware/DRP-AS/DRPAttendanceSystem.exe
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Windows.Forms
>       Assembly-versie: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32-versie: 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System
>       Assembly-versie: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32-versie: 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Drawing
>       Assembly-versie: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32-versie: 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Data
>       Assembly-versie: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32-versie: 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Core
>       Assembly-versie: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32-versie: 4.7.3110.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Configuration
>       Assembly-versie: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32-versie: 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Data.resources
>       Assembly-versie: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32-versie: 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Data.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_nl_b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.resources.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Xml
>       Assembly-versie: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32-versie: 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Transactions
>       Assembly-versie: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32-versie: 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.EnterpriseServices
>       Assembly-versie: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32-versie: 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- mscorlib.resources
>       Assembly-versie: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32-versie: 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/mscorlib.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_nl_b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.resources.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Windows.Forms.resources
>       Assembly-versie: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32-versie: 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
>
> ### CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_nl_b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.resources.dll
>
> ************** JIT-foutopsporing ************** Als u JIT-foutopsporing wilt inschakelen, moet in het configuratiebestand
>   voor deze toepassing of computer (machine.config) de waarde
>   jitDebugging in het gedeelte system.windows.forms zijn ingesteld. De
>   toepassing moet ook zijn gecompileerd terwijl foutopsporing was
>   ingeschakeld.
>
> Bijvoorbeeld:
>
> Wanneer JIT-foutopsporing is ingeschakeld, worden onverwerkte
>   uitzonderingen naar het JIT-foutopsporingsprogramma gestuurd dat op de
>   computer is geregistreerd en worden niet door dit dialoogvenster
>   verwerkt.

Comment: Did you install localdb? What error you get at which line of what code?

Comment: Is your code creating the database if it doesn't exist?  If not, you need deploy the database file along with your application on the other computers.  For anything more in-depth, we will need to see some code and exact error messages.

Comment: how is the other machine.... getting access to this DB... did you copy it? does it have the install necessary to read the db files.., you need to specify a lot more. what is local to you... aka what does the connection string look like.

Comment: I did install localdb yeah (at least, I've installed SqlLocalDB.MSI). The database file is simply stored on the other computer that I want to use it with. My connectionstring is: private static string connectionstring = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='G:\DRPAttendance\Medewerkers.mdf';Integrated Security=True";

Comment: And by the way, the error occurs when I launch the program outside of Visual Studio. So it has got nothing to do with the code itself. It's really the connection. Can't get the full error code, since it's too long for a comment.

Comment: The connection string you posted as comment points to a location on the drive `G:`, but in your question you say files are on the drive `C:`. Have you tried updating the connection string accordingly? Also, what error message are you getting? Please edit your question and add the full error details to it (comments are meant for discussion, if you have new important information please edit your question and add them)

Comment: I did of course edit the connectiongstring accordingly each time I tested it with a different location. :) The G: drive is the one that I want to start using, the C: drive is just for testing purposes, and has been the drive used during programma. I will edit my question with the full error.

Comment: It doesn't seem to like the instance name of your connection string (`(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB`).  On the computer throwing the error, run the command `SqlLocalDB.exe i`. This will list all the instances running on that system.  The exe can usually be found in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn`, you may need to slightly change the number in that path depending on your version.

Comment: SQL Client will only connect to the mdf file if it is on same machine as server.  So you can use any local drive like c:\ or d:\   put not a network drive (unless it is mounted on local machine).  This is a limitation of SQL Server and not code in c#.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found out where it went wrong. My code was 100% alright. As it turned out however, the SqlLocalDB.MSI file was not ‘compatible’ with the DB I’ve used in my program. It was ‘derived’ from SQL Server 2014, whereas I needed the one derived from the 2016 version.

It would’ve worked nonetheless, by indeed changing the connectionstring, but for some reason I could not get that part right. So I went looking a bit further and found out that when using SQL Server 2014, the part in my connectionstring that says MSSQLLocalDB, had to be changed to V11.0 or something. However, when using SQL Server 2016, MSSQLLocalDB is correct after all.

So I sorta fixed it myself. Thanks anyway for the helpful replies everyone. :)